# Unable to test interaction on html UI elements within WkWebView in iOS, using Appium

Tags: ios, appium, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, appium-ios

I have a hybrid app which has native view and some WkWebViews which render html/js content.
We are trying to create a bed of automation tests using Appium. We are able to capture the interaction on native iOS UI elements by their accessibilityID. However, once we are inside a WkWebView, Appium is not able to differentiate each html UI element (like a button or a label) and hence we are not able to test and assert of something changed/updated on tap.

Does Appium not support this kind of hybrid app testing?
Their documentation claim support for WkWebView.

Comment: Hi rlr, Have you got it working? Any update on this. We are facing similar issues with Cordova based Hybrid app. Thanks

Comment: No. We gave up on the idea of using Appium for iOS. We went ahead with XCTest and XCUITest framework for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Appium [supports WkWebView](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) automation starting with version **1.5.3**, however there were reports that it didn't work in some cases, e.g. multiple views on iOS 8.

I suggest to try with latest appium (`npm install -g appium@beta`) & inspect elements with Safari remote debug to verify your locators, since appium-desktop inspector is only designed to inspect native apps.

If there is no luck, [post issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues) with your appium service log, so that community can check if its a bug